# rmarkdown::render to compile LaTeX documents

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

[This example LaTeX file](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/latex-example.html) compiles just fine for me using Rstudio, TexShop, and `pdflatex example.tex`. But `rmarkdown::render` does not work.

```
> rmarkdown::render("example.tex", output_format = "pdf_document")
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS example.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output example.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.88 \documentclass

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>
```

Is there a way to tell `rmarkdown` that I'm starting with a LaTeX document? I am using

- Mac OS 10.11.5
- R 3.3.0
- rmarkdown 0.9.6
- pandoc 1.13.2
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. `tools::texi2pdf("example.tex")` worked for me with Rstudio and R from the command line. [The R GUI failed in error, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021639/texi2pdf-fails-with-the-r-gui)